# Android @RequirePermission highlights method in red in onRequestPermissionsResult granted

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

Android Studio (`2.2.3`) warns me against a method I called that is annoted with `@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`.

I would be OK with such a warning, but in my case, it's non-sense: I am calling the method within `onRequestPermissionsResult` where I check that the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has been indeed granted :

```
if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            CSVUtils.setup(); // -> is highlighted in red!!
```

So following the warning advice, I am using `checkSelfPermission()` but then Android Studio tells me that this is **SDK 23** while I am targeting SDK 21 as minimum while I am in a method that could only be called in SDK 23 or newer. This really defeats the purpose, because I have all the code made to check the permission if user is running SDK 23 or newer, so why should I have to do more check ?

In any case, this is not really a problem, just that I don't like being warned this way when I don't need to annotate my methods with `@RequirePermission`... what can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this annotation above the method to avoid warning
`@SuppressWarnings({"MissingPermission"})`

Comment: Thanks ! I was actually thinking of doing this, but I did not know what to pass in `@SuppressWarnings` but I went back here knowing someone would have given this solution and you have ! :)